# Laptop/Desktop Sleep Events

Tags: c#, .net, sleep

I was wondering if there was an event that is triggered when a laptop or desktop goes into sleep mode.

An example would be: 
When a user is working on his/her laptop and he/she flips the monitor down, the laptop goes into sleep mode.

Or when a user goes to Start → Shutdown → Sleep.

Are there any events built into .NET that determine this?

Comment: I have noticed the Win32 event PowerMode and the mode of suspended, where the operating system gets suspended but i dont know if that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGPowerMonitor.aspx) and [these MSDN reference articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968807(v=VS.85).aspx).

To find out C# DLLImport declarations visit [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net)

**UPD**

Also check [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode8.aspx)

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for power management tools or change the power... i'm looking for when the computer sleeps or is on idle for a long time and the computer changes.

Comment: RegisterPowerSettingNotification function will help you. Then in WndProc method you should check Message value.

Comment: See update, by link provided source code how to handle it in C#.